# Convert slide up footer to slide in

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, panel, footer, slideup

£50.00 if some one can help me with this

I have found this simple slide up footer
http://return-true.com/examples/slidefooter2.html

and wonder if any one can convert it to slide in from the left of the screen instaed of the bottom of the screen
the code at the moment looks like this

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        var open = false;
        $('#footerSlideButton').click(function () {
            if(open === false) {
                $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '300px' });
                $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'bottom left');
                open = true;
            } else {
                $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '0px' });
                $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'top left');
                open = false;
            }
        });     
    });
</script>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background: #EFEFEF;
}
#footerSlideContainer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
}
#footerSlideButton {
    background: url(sliderButton.png) top left no-repeat transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -55px;
    right: 20px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#footerSlideContent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    background: #251b15;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border: none;
    font-family: DejaVuSansBook, Sans-Serif;
}
#footerSlideContent h3 {
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #9AC941;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
#footerSlideContent ul {
    color: #EE8D40;
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height: 2em;
}
#footerSlideText {
    padding: 15px 10px 25px 25px;
}
#lookHere {
    font-family: DejaVuSansBook, Sans-Serif;
}
#lookHere h1, #lookHere h2 {
    font-size: 20em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #AAAAAA;
}
#lookHere h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
}
#lookHere span.orange {
    color: #EE8D40;
}
#lookHere span.green {
    color: #9AC941;
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div id="lookHere">
<h1>Huh?!</h1>
<h2>This page isn't blank. Save some space. <span class="orange">Look</span> to the <span class="green">bottom right</span>.</h2>
</div>
<div id="footerSlideContainer">
    <div id="footerSlideButton"></div>
    <div id="footerSlideContent">
        <div id="footerSlideText">
            <h3>Hey! I'm a Sliding Footer</h3>
            <p>What's a Sliding Footer? Well I'm a cool little element which can be hidden from view, and revealed when the user wants to see me.</p>
            <p>What can you use me for? Well look at all this stuff:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Sales information</li>
                <li>Important updates</li>
                <li>Unobtrusive about panel</li>
                <li>Or just a good ol' footer</li>
            </ul>
            <p>There are obviously many other uses, but these are the few useful ones I can think of.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this ... This will work when users mouse over the small 5% bottom right corner of the screen and slowly go back again over a 1 second period when they leave the footer ...

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#footerSlideContainer').css({position:'fixed',left:'95%',bottom:'0',height:'100px'});
    $('#footerSlideContainer').mouseover(function(){
        $('#footerSlideContainer').animate({left: '0%'});
    });
    $('#footerSlideContainer').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#footerSlideContainer').animate({left: '95%'},1000);
    });
});`